# Не понимаю, почему не работает clean method для поля формы? При попытке зарегистрировать пользователя, django не берёт во внимание мой метод

Tags: ajax, django, form

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

        def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if data == 'registration':
            raise form.ValidationError('Your nickname can not be "registration"!')
        return data
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .ajax_mixin import AjaxableResponseMixin
from .forms import UserForm

class Registration(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
template_name = 'user/registration.html'
form_class = UserForm
```

mixin.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class AjaxableResponseMixin:
def form_invalid(self, form):
    response = super().form_invalid(form)
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
    else:
        return response

def form_valid(self, form):
    response = super().form_valid(form)
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        data = {
            'slug': self.object.slug,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return response
```

Comment: `clean_uesrname` - может быть, дело в опечатке?

Comment: Храни тебя господь !

Comment: Хотя не смотря на это, он всё равно позволяет создать пользователя с именем регистрация.

Comment: а `form_valid` в принципе вызывается?

Comment: Вообще если это стандартный пользователь, то для его создания лучше использовать `UserCreationForm`

Comment: Это AbstractUser, и что вы имели ввиду с form_valid?

Comment: И ещё поправьте отступы с `clean_username`. С такими отступами, как в первом блоке кода, он не выполнится. Если функция clean у вас относится к классу Meta, то она работать не будет

Comment: Я не понял про отступы, поэтому переписал весь файл, не помогло. И с классом мета тоже не понятно, я его ни где не использовал.